# From string to numeric

Tags: c++, string, double

I have tried to make a small function that converts integers and float point numbers and saves them as strings, to double type, everything works, but when i input many digits behind comma, something goes wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
/////////////////////////////////////CONVERTer FUNCTION/////////
double StrToNum(string InStr)
{
int a=0;
double b,OutInt=0,DecVal=0,DoubleOut;
for(a;a<=InStr.length();a++)
{
if(InStr[a]=='.' || InStr[a]==','){break;}
if(InStr[a]=='0'){OutInt=OutInt*10+0;}        
if(InStr[a]=='1'){OutInt=OutInt*10+1;}  
if(InStr[a]=='2'){OutInt=OutInt*10+2;}  
if(InStr[a]=='3'){OutInt=OutInt*10+3;}  
if(InStr[a]=='4'){OutInt=OutInt*10+4;}  
if(InStr[a]=='5'){OutInt=OutInt*10+5;}  
if(InStr[a]=='6'){OutInt=OutInt*10+6;}  
if(InStr[a]=='7'){OutInt=OutInt*10+7;}  
if(InStr[a]=='8'){OutInt=OutInt*10+8;}  
if(InStr[a]=='9'){OutInt=OutInt*10+9;}    
}


for(a=0;a<=InStr.length();a++)
{
if(InStr[a]=='.' || InStr[a]==','){a+=1; b=1; break;}
}
for(a;a<=InStr.length();a++)
{
if(InStr[a]=='0'){ b+=1;}        
if(InStr[a]=='1'){DecVal=DecVal+1/pow(10,b); b+=1;}  
if(InStr[a]=='2'){DecVal=DecVal+2/pow(10,b); b+=1;}  
if(InStr[a]=='3'){DecVal=DecVal+3/pow(10,b); b+=1;}  
if(InStr[a]=='4'){DecVal=DecVal+4/pow(10,b); b+=1;}  
if(InStr[a]=='5'){DecVal=DecVal+5/pow(10,b); b+=1;}  
if(InStr[a]=='6'){DecVal=DecVal+6/pow(10,b); b+=1;}  
if(InStr[a]=='7'){DecVal=DecVal+7/pow(10,b); b+=1;}  
if(InStr[a]=='8'){DecVal=DecVal+8/pow(10,b); b+=1;}  
if(InStr[a]=='9'){DecVal=DecVal+9/pow(10,b); b+=1;}  
}  


DoubleOut=OutInt+DecVal;
return DoubleOut;   
}
/////////////////////////////////////CONVERTer FUNCTION/////////


int main ()
{
string InStr;
double DoubleOut;

cout<<"Please input number(will be saved as string)"<<endl;
cin>>InStr;

DoubleOut=StrToNum(InStr);
cout<<"Integer converted from string= "<<DoubleOut<<endl;


system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should look into the switch syntax ? e.g. switch(InStr[a]) { case '1', case '2', etc... There would be less redundances.

Comment: Dat formatting! **Dat redundancy!**

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier Not quite. Since the standard guarantees that, `digit - '0'` would work just fine.

Comment: Could you elaborate on `something goes wrong` please! It's unclear what you're asking. Your code looks strange but I can't spot obvious errors for now!

Comment: when i input for example 12.1234, output is the same. but when i input 12.123456789 it returns value 12.123457

Comment: @user2929512 Edit this as update to your question, and I'll retract the close vote.

Comment: It does not "return" a shorter number, at least not until your input crosses the limit of *double accuracy* (which hovers around 15 digits). The default output precision rounds at 6 decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting strings to floating point numbers is non-trivial. The obvious approach is to use the standard C or C++ library, e.g., `strtod()`. If you really want to convert values yourself, have a look William Clinger's [How to Read Floating Point Numbers Accurately](http://www.cesura17.net/~will/Professional/Research/Papers/howtoread.pdf).

You didn't specify "many" in your question but note that `double` can only represent 15, well, actually `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10`, decimal digits accurately. If you have more than that digits, the result needs to be rounded.

From an implementation point of view: once you have determined that a character `c` is a digit, you can compute the digit's value using `c - '0'`, i.e., you might want to use this formula with `isdigit()`. Also, using `pow()` is fairly expensive abd probably not as accurate as computing a running factor.

Comment: thanks for answer, but can problem be that program have to count sum of usual decimal number, and normalised decimal number. i.e. would it be correct that 0.1 + 2e^-2 =0.12??
p.s. sorry if my english is bad :(

Comment: @user2929512: dealing with floating point numbers and expect decimal numbers as a result is tricky, to say the least. Converting `"0.12"` as `1 / 10.0 + 2 / 100.0` will probably give a worse approximation than computing it as `(1 * 10 + 2) / 100.0`. The problem is that binary floating point numbers cannot, in general, represent decimal numbers, i.e., in the first computation the value potentially rounded 3 times while it is only rounded once in the computation.

Comment: @user2929512: You may also want to have a look at David Goldberg's [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).